# python: how can I catch "OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument" exception in my code

Tags: python, exception

Here is code snippet that works fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

with open("/proc/net/xt_recent/BLACKLIST", 'w') as f:
    try:
        f.write(f'+1.1.1.1\n')
    except:
        print('error')
```

When I try to write some garbage, ie:

```
        f.write(f'asdf\n')
```

I get this error:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./xx.py", line 5, in <module>
    f.write(f'asdf\n')
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Why does my `except` statement not catch this error?
How can I catch this, and handle this myself?

Comment: Do you get the same error when you have the open function in try block as well?